# Does calling setText on a TextView causes it to redraw even if it was the same text being set again?

Tags: android, android-view

I have an `activity` that has lots of `TextViews`. Currently, I use separate observers on the `ViewModel` for each separate value of each TextView, so they update upon the change of data in the `ViewModel`.

But, it would be easier if I just observe over an object containing all the data that is to be presented in that activity.

Would that cause all the `TextViews` to redraw even if I call `setText` with the same values that the `TextViews` are already having? Or, only the `TextViews` where the new text value is different than the old one would redraw?

What would the default behavior be like? And also for other types of views, like `Checkboxes` or `ImageViews`?

Comment: yes, every textview will re-write the value if you do so....this case applies to all imageviews and check boxes

Answer (score 0):

Android has a method named `checkForRelayout` in `TextView` element that calls in `setText`.
With a short glance at it, we can find out that view will be invalidated

For `CheckBox` view element it saves the current value in `mPrivateFlags` and in the first line of `setSelected` method it compares with his current value and if it didn't changed, then doesn't call `invalidate`

For `ImageView` it checks with old value and if the drawable was the same, it doesn't call `invalidate` method